# How to understand and use bit operation for programming

Tags: binary

I got the following code using bit operation from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216248/how-to-use-mathematica-to-solve-this-problem-of-planting-tree/216256#216256):

```
lis = Complement[Range[0, 15], {7, 14, 15}]
    ans = Tuples[lis, 3] // 
       Select[#, 
         BitAnd[#1, #2, #3] == 0 && BitAnd[4 #1, 2 #2, #3] == 0 && 
             BitAnd[#1, 2 #2, 4 #3] == 0 & @@ # &] &;
    nums = Length@ans
    GroupBy[ans, 
        Total@Flatten@IntegerDigits[#, 2] &] // #[Max[Keys[#]]] & // 
      IntegerDigits[#, 2, 4] & // TableForm /@ # &
```

But I'm not familiar with bit operations. How can I understand the meaning of this code and find more examples of bit operations?

Comment: This code treats four-bit integers as arrays of four Boolean values (represented by binary digits 0 and 1). The selection code filters out cases where there's a binary 1-digit on the same, incrementing or decrementing position of the binary representations (or the array positions) of tuple values using the `BitAnd` operation (multiplication by a power of two acts as a position shifter).

Comment: @kirma Thank you very much for your comment, which makes me understand the operation mechanism of this code.

Comment: Copied the comment to an answer, as it seems to resolve the issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code treats four-bit integers as arrays of four Boolean values (represented by binary digits 0 and 1). The selection code filters out cases where there's a binary 1-digit on the same, incrementing or decrementing position of the binary representations (or the array positions) of tuple values using the `BitAnd` operation (multiplication by a power of two acts as a position shifter).